# Android: How to check IOException cause when drive is out of space

Tags: android, ioexception, try-catch-finally

How to check IOException cause on the catch?

Is `e.getCause().getMessage()` always returns the same string on all the android versions and devices for the same cause? Is it a good approach to check if IOException's cause is `android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)` for checking if the user's device is out of space on that specific drive?

```
try {
    // Here I'm writing a file with OutputStream
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Check if IOException cause equals android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
} finally {

}
```

Comment: Read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966296/ioexception-for-drive-full-or-out-of-space?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I was aware of that post and for now, I'm checking `IOException`'s cause by checking it's message. I thought maybe there is another or better to say safer (if checking message is not safe at all) approach to get the result.

Answer (score 3):

It is not usually a good idea to rely on error messages as they **might** vary with OS versions.
If targeting API level 21 or above, there is an elegant way to find the actual root cause of the IOException based on an error code. (*ENOSPC* in your case)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/OsConstants#ENOSPC

It may be checked like this:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof ErrnoException) { 
        int errorNumber = ((ErrnoException) e.getCause()).errno;
        if (errorNumber == OsConstants.ENOSPC) {
            // Out of space
        }
    }
}
```

**errno** is a public field in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/ErrnoException